# Install Denso package in ROS kinetic

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I want to work with the Denso vs60 robot. After I started to model the robot I found out that somebody did already the work, so no need to do it again ;)
I found this [this package](http://wiki.ros.org/denso?distro=indigo) of the robot but the install instructions are only available for hydro and indigo. Unfortunately, I am running on kinetic. On their [github](https://github.com/start-jsk/denso/tree/kinetic-devel) I figured out that there is a "kinetic-devel" branch.
My question is, how do I get this branch working (installed)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266755/install-denso-package-in-ros-kinetic/) by [Kaonashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30379/kaonashi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2017-07-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Assuming that you have a catkin workspace in your home folder that is called catkin_ws, you can do:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/start-jsk/denso
git checkout kinetic-devel
cd ..
catkin_make
```

Solve compilation errors if any, and assuming you have this line `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` in your `~/.bashrc`, you can use the package as you would with any other ROS package.

Good luck!

P.S. If you don't have your own catkin workspace please follow this [tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace), and then follow the steps I provided.

---

Originally posted by [gstavrinos](https://answers.ros.org/users/27452/gstavrinos/) with karma: 641 on 2017-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-19**:
I would add a `rosdep install --from-paths ~/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src` right before the `catkin_make`.

**Comment by [Kaonashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30379/kaonashi/) on 2017-07-19**:
Thanks for your answers and suggestions.
@gvdhoorn could you elaborate on your suggested command (for learning purposes). What will it do?
Nevertheless, since the denso package has so many dependencies I decided to set up a virtual machine with Ubuntu12.04 and install the package there.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-07-20**:
If you install things from sources, you'll have to make sure that you install all dependencies first. That is what `rosdep` does.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with [the already accepted answer](http://answers.ros.org/question/266755/install-denso-package-in-ros-kinetic/?answer=266776#post-id-266776). This is a simple Catkin workspace or Git question, may not even ROS so I suggest going through the tutorials.

Besides that, as of July 20th 2017 the denso package will most likely not compile or run due to the missing upstream dependency. There's [an open pull request for fixing that](https://github.com/start-jsk/denso/pull/82), which you'd be appreciated if you could give a try on by like:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/denso    (assuming you've already cloned the repo)
git remote add ompugao https://github.com/ompugao/denso.git
git fetch ompugao
git checkout kinetic-devel
git rebase ompugao/kinetic-devel
```

Then build the package in the same way as suggested.

---

**UPDATE** 20170809 `denso` package has just been [released into ROS Kinetic](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/15749). Its binary should become available in the [next public sync](https://discourse.ros.org/c/release/kinetic).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-07-20

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kaonashi](https://answers.ros.org/users/30379/kaonashi/) on 2017-07-20**:
I get the following errors: Rosdep wants to install libgazebo5-dev, which is simply not present. Catkin_make can't find the package configuration file provided by  "open_controllers_interface".
Nevertheless, the Denso package works fine in indigo under Ubuntu 14.04